# How to add images on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a JFrame window with text and an image. However, I keep receiving a null pointer exception. Here is my code, would someone be able to help out? There isn't anything very complicated, it was just an example given to me. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout; // specifies how comments are arranged
import javax.swing.JFrame; // provides basic window features
import javax.swing.JLabel; // displays text and images
import javax.swing.SwingConstants; // common constants used with Swing
import javax.swing.Icon; // interface used to manipulate images
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; // loads images

class LabelFrame extends JFrame{

private final JLabel label1; // JLabel with just text
private final JLabel label2; // JLabel constructed with text and icon
private final JLabel label3; // JLabel with added text and icon

// LabelFrame constructor adds JLabels to JFrame
LabelFrame() {
    
    super("Testing label");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // set frame layout
    
    // JLabel constructor with a string argument
    label1 = new JLabel("Label with text");
    label1.setToolTipText("This is label1");
    add(label1); // add label1 to JFrame
    
    // JLabel constructor with string, Icon and alignment arguments
    Icon bug = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bug1.png"));
    label2 = new JLabel("Label with text and icon", bug, SwingConstants.LEFT);
    label2.setToolTipText("This is label2");
    add(label2); // add labe2 to JFrame
    
    label3 = new JLabel(); // JLabel constructor with no arguments
    label3.setText("Label with icon and text at botton");
    label3.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label3.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label3.setToolTipText("This is label3");
    add(label3); // add label3 to JFrame
    
}
}
public class LabelTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    LabelFrame labelFrame = new LabelFrame();
    labelFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    labelFrame.setSize(260, 180);
    labelFrame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at LabelFrame.<init>(LabelTest.java:28)
at LabelTest.main(LabelTest.java:46)
```

Comment: The image must be found on your classpath.

Comment: @camickr I have added it to the source folder but there is still the same error message

Comment: The classpath is were your class files are located.